# C++ conversion from char * to unsigned char?

Tags: c++, path, compiler-errors, registry, type-conversion

Hello I'm trying to create a take a program path and put in in a registry file, but I keep on having an error. Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <windows.h> 
#include <winuser.h> 
#include <tchar.h>
#include <limits>

using namespace std;

void reg() {
char buffer[MAX_PATH];

GetModuleFileName(NULL,buffer,sizeof(buffer));

const unsigned char Path[ MAX_PATH ] = {buffer};

::HKEY Handle_Key = 0;

::RegSetValueEx( Handle_Key, "My Directory", 0, 1, Path, sizeof Path  );
};
```

The error I'm getting says

> invalid conversion from 'char*' to 'unsigned char' [-fpermissive]

I have spent hours looking for a solution, but I can't find one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem, I'm guessing, is this line

```
const unsigned char Path[ MAX_PATH ] = {buffer};
```

The problem here is that you try to create an array of single characters with a character pointer.

You only use that variable as a temporary for the `RegSetValueEx` call, so you don't really need it. Instead call that function with `buffer` directly.

Also, you should not use `sizeof` here, since that will put *all* of the buffer in the registry, and not only the actual string. Use `strlen`.

Like:

```
::RegSetValueEx( Handle_Key, "My Directory", 0, 1,
                 reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(buffer),
                 strlen(buffer));
```

Comment: `static_cast`? I got the error message that `invalid static_cast from type 'char [260]' to type 'unsigned char*'`.

Comment: @johnchen902 Updated my answer to use `reinterpret_cast`.